# spm: testTarget unable to find c++ header

Tags: swift

I've successfully imported and created a c++ library and linked it with a new swift package.

The swift target which depends on the cpp target imports the cpp bridge correctly, and recognizes every struct, enum and functions in the c++ library.

However, the testtarget causes one issue and is not able to recognize one of the functions in the c++ implementation which is recognized in the swift implementation.

The dependencies in the package are

import PackageDescription

```
let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftSGP4",
    platforms: [
        .iOS("16"),
        .macOS("13"),
],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "SGP4",
            targets: ["SGP4"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/triple7/SwiftCelesTrak", branch:"main"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SGP4",
            path: "Sources/SGP4"),
        .target(
            name: "SwiftSGP4",
            dependencies: ["SGP4", .product(name: "SwiftCelesTrak", package: "SwiftCelesTrak")]),
            .testTarget(
            name: "SwiftSGP4Tests",
            dependencies: ["SwiftSGP4", "SGP4"]),
    ]
)
```

The Undefined symbol: _sgp4init error in the testTarget seems to complain that it can't find the function in the header from my c++ library which has been linked with an extern "C" definition. This makes the swiftSgp4 target be able to implement functions dependent on the SGP4 c++ target, but not the tests.